# How to go through all partitions in hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, partition

I want to update column's value in all partitions. Before I found `insert overwrite` can be used to update data. My current statement is

`insert OVERWRITE table s_job PARTITION(pt = '20190101') select case job_name when 'Job' then 'system' end from s_job;`

However, it must specify certain partition. What I want is to update the value in all partitions, I don't know how to do. Is there a way using hive sql to go through all partitions in hive? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dynamic partitioning:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert OVERWRITE table s_job PARTITION(pt) 
select --Add all columns in their original order
       col1,
       col2,
       ...
       coln,
       case job_name when 'Job' then 'system' end as job_name,
       pt --partition column should be the last one
  from s_job;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic partitioning](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions) for such type of tasks