# Hive: How do I INSERT data FROM a PARTITIONED table INTO a PARTITIONED table?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, cloudera

This is an extension of a previous question I asked: [Is it possible to change an existing column's metadata on an EXTERNAL table that is defined by an AVRO schema file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369559/is-it-possible-to-change-an-existing-columns-metadata-on-an-external-table-that)

**Question:** In Hive 2.1.1, how do I INSERT data FROM a PARTITIONED table INTO a PARTITIONED table? What is the correct syntax? I have seen material all over the internet and none of it seems to be working.

**Frustration:** I have posted way too many questions on the same topic: how to change data from an existing STRING column into a BIGINT column on a table that is EXTERNAL and created by an AVRO metadata file and stored as AVRO. None of that seems to work. So, now I have created a duplicate *_new table with the updated metadata and I am now trying to INSERT the existing data INTO the new table by SELECTing from the existing table. And, that is not working. I have tried numerous permutations of the HQL to perform this task and have received a corresponding permutation of errors.

HQL seems to require a PHD in rocket science... This simple task should not be so f'ng difficult.

**Sample query:**

```
INSERT INTO TableName_New
--PARTITION (partition_year="2000", partition_month="01", partition_date="2000-01-01")
PARTITION (partition_year, partition_month, partition_date)
SELECT Column1, Column2
     --,CAST(Column3 AS BIGINT) Column3
     ,Column3
,partition_year, partition_month, partition_date
--,partition_year, partition_month, partition_date
FROM TableName
WHERE partition_year="2000"
    AND partition_month="01"
    AND partition_date="2000-01-01"
```

**Typical Error Message:**

> Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code
>   2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

**Update:**

The error appears to be in the SELECT statement. Now, I can SELECT * no problem. But, when I SELECT either by a specific column or using a WHERE constraint, then I was getting the error above in HUE. I decided to run the same command in HIVE CLI and I think I may have gotten the underlying error:

**Excerpted from below:**

> org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found long, expecting union

Now, what strikes me as odd here is that I did DROP and CREATED the new table using the modified AVRO metadata file and I migrated a single PARTITION (contains 3 files). I verified that both the AVRO metadata file and the PARTITION file have the same metadata for Column3. But, in HUE, the column's metadata shows as BIGINT. It appears that Hive's metastore is not correctly up-to-date (I suspect this is from all of the testing and troubleshooting we have done). How can I correct this?

Regardless, I decided to go ahead and create a whole new table using the old metadata and copied the partition files over within HDFS CLI. In HUE, Column3's metadata now shows correctly as STRING. I then added the partition to the table. I can SELECT * no problem, but I am still getting the same excerpted error above when I try to SELECT either by column or WHERE constraint. I am wondering if column3's metadata was updated for all of the rows within the partition file while the AVRO metadata contained at the top of the partition file was not changed. I'm kind of stuck right now and am open to ideas.

Problem 1: How can I fix the original table's metadata in Hive, considering the AVRO file is correct?

Problem 2: How do I fix the inability to SELECT from the old temp table if the partition files were somehow modified when I ran the `ALTER COLUMN ... PARTITION (...) CHANGE COLUMN Column3 Column3 BIGINT CASCADE` command? Do I just run the same command but with STRING instead of BIGINT?
**Full Error Message: **

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error
>   while processing writable
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroGenericRecordWritable@439b15f2
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:169)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1731)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168) Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive
>   Runtime Error while processing writable
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroGenericRecordWritable@439b15f2
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:492)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:160)
>           ... 8 more Caused by: **org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found long, expecting union**
>           at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:292)
>           at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
>           at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:267)
>           at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179)
>           at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
>           at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:232)
>           at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:222)
>           at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:175)
>           at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
>           at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:145)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroDeserializer$SchemaReEncoder.reencode(AvroDeserializer.java:110)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroDeserializer.deserialize(AvroDeserializer.java:174)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe.deserialize(AvroSerDe.java:220)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.readRow(MapOperator.java:125)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.access$200(MapOperator.java:89)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:483)
>           ... 9 more

Comment: And what is the error message? Please add it to the question

Comment: This is not informative. Try to find jobtracker logs of failed task

Comment: @Leftjoin I know, unfortunately, I do not have access to that site. My question was more general: what is the proper syntax to perform the operation that I am trying to perform?

Comment: Syntax seems good. There are many other similar questions about dynamic partition load like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55135155/2700344 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/55445440/2700344 You need detailed error message to understand what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you can try

1. I assume column 3 is of bigint type in your new table and string in your old table you can cast and use colaese on it  something like colaese (cast(col3 as bigint),0) as col3 in your select statement try doing same thing on all your type casted column
2. Try insert overwrite

If you are able to query the select part then there must be problem in insert part
Please comment you updates lets figure it out

Comment: I have updated my question with additional details.

Comment: Hive Runtime Error while processing writable org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroGenericRecordWritable@439b15f2 at this is culprit. Are you able to query select statement

Comment: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found long, expecting union at. Are you sure data is not corrupted can you execute a query that performs MR tasks like groupby or something

Comment: I can do `SELECT *` but neither `SELECT DISTINCT Column3` nor `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE <PartitionColumnConstraintsHere>` work.

Comment: Yes select * will work as it does not execute MR and directly prints data to console.Seems some problem with your data becoz i have faced similar issues in quering corrupted data this is why u are not able to query data

Comment: i hope you have already gone through it https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5e0e93f9-3c02-40dc-afa4-656faacde69b/cannot-read-data-from-hive-external-table-to-a-avro-serilized-files-failed-with-exception?forum=hdinsight

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480155/failed-with-exception-java-io-ioexceptionorg-apache-avro-avrotypeexception-fou

Comment: It was bad data in the file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Happy to know, finally you found root cause of your problem.